# RNC Slider lint FAILED on ./gradlew clean build and release apk crashes on app start

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin

Before assembling release, I'm trying to make clean build but it throws error and fails the task. When I generate release apk (succesfully generates), after installing it on my LG G4 phone (also tried Samsung Galaxy J3), it is crashing and not starting.

My app succesfully works with `react-native run-android` on my phone.

Before assembling release build, I typed

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew buildcache
./gradlew clean build
```

and the last command always gives errors.

After adding

```
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
```

to RNC Slider's build.gradle file as the errors say, `./gradlew clean build` succesfully finishes its task. But still I can't open the app after generating and installing release apk.

`./gradlew clean build` error:

```
...
> Task :@react-native-community_slider:lint FAILED
Ran lint on variant release: 3 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 3 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///D:/React/Pure%20RN/dassist/node_modules/@react-native-community/slider/android/build/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///D:/React/Pure%20RN/dassist/node_modules/@react-native-community/slider/android/build/reports/lint-results.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_slider:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...

  Errors found:

  D:\React\Pure RN\dassist\node_modules\@react-native-community\slider\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\slider\ReactSliderManager.java:68: Error: Value must be ? 0 (was -2) [Range]
              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU¦LD FAILED in 35s
163 actionable tasks: 154 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

And this is a part of the xml report file (warnings excluded) mentioned in output logs:

```
<issues format="5" by="lint 3.3.1">

    <issue
        id="Range"
        severity="Error"
        message="Value must be ≥ 0 (was -2)"
        category="Correctness"
        priority="6"
        summary="Outside Range"
        explanation="Some parameters are required to in a particular numerical range; this check makes sure that arguments passed fall within the range. For arrays, Strings and collections this refers to the size or length."
        errorLine1="            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,"
        errorLine2="            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">
        <location
            file="D:\React\Pure RN\dassist\node_modules\@react-native-community\slider\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\slider\ReactSliderManager.java"
            line="68"
            column="13"/>
    </issue>

</issues>
```

Comment: run './gradlew lintfix' and then do ./gradlew clean build.

Comment: @RanjanKumar Thanks for help. But `./gradlew lintfix` fixed some other errors (about AsyncStorage and NetInfo), not the error of Slider. It still shows the same error on clean build.

Comment: @harky were you able to resolve this? I am getting this error now

Comment: @GraemePaul I've made a new RN 0.61.2 init and rewrote my all of code. It's working now.